# iOS - Monitoring app flow from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, key-value-observing

I am trying to create **Singleton** that it would be initialised from **AppDelegate**. The purpose is to monitor all the `UIViewControllers` (the active one) and print on console the kind of class (as proof of concept). So my basic idea is to initialise the singleton in `AppDelegate` and pass as parameter a reference of `AppDelegate`. Then somehow I must monitor which one is the active view.

**For example:** View A B C
A is the first view in Navigation Controller. My Singleton knows that the current view is A. Then we push view B and Singleton is notified that view B is now the current view. Same with C. Now we pop C and Singleton knows that the current view is B.

Is any kind **KVO** or **NSNotification** for notifying my singleton that a new `UIView` is appeard/removed? Any alternatives for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After registering for all notification I found out about `UINavigationControllerDidShowViewControllerNotification`.

With this observer:
    `[notifyCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(viewAppeared:) name:@"UINavigationControllerDidShowViewControllerNotification" object:nil];` I am able to monitor the activity of the UINavigationController.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same but for UITabBarController?

Answer (score 0):

You can get current View controller by just making a view controller object in appdelegate like

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *currentViewController;
```

and then on the view will Appear of your current view controller give the current reference to the app delegate object like

```
AppDelegate *myAppd = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    myAppd.currentViewController = self;
```

This way you get your current active view.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to pick a particular method you want to know about and intercept it.

Here, I create a category on `UIViewController` and provide a method I want called whenever the controller's `viewWillAppear:` would normally be called:

```
#include <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIViewController (Swap)

+ (void)load
{
    NSLog(@"Exchange implementations");
    method_exchangeImplementations(
     class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(viewWillAppear:)),
     class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(customViewWillAppear:)));
}

- (void)customViewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Call the original method, using its new name
    [self customViewWillAppear:animated];

    NSLog(@"Firing %@ for %@", VIEW_CONTROLLER_APPEARED, self);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:VIEW_CONTROLLER_APPEARED
                                                        object:self];
}

@end
```

After that, it's just a case of listening for the notification in whatever object needs to know (e.g. your **Singleton**).

Comment: The issue is that I want the Singleton to be more general and works on existing projects. That's why I want it to have as parameter the AppDelegate.

Comment: I don't understand how that invalidates this strategy.  If you can add the Singleton to a project, you can also add a category to the project.

Comment: I would convert it to a framework at a later stage. That's why I am trying to find it if I can monitor the flow of the app without any other code